# I am having issue with python, I am trying to make QRcode creating app

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, png, qr-code

I am facing problem in the clicked() function which has to be executed when the button is pressed
I have defined the variables but it shows the error message of 'variable not defined'

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyqrcode as qr
import png
from pyqrcode import QRCode
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("QR")
label = tk.Label(window,text="QR maker",font=("Helvetica",50)).pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="Enter link",font=("Helvetica",10)).pack()
txt = tk.Entry(window,width=50).pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="Enter size",font=("Helvetica",10)).pack()
txt2 = tk.Entry(window,width=10).pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="enter name",font=("Helvetica",10)).pack()
txt3 = tk.Entry(window,width=50).pack()

def clicked():
Qstr = txt.get()
a = int(txt2.get())
b = txt3.get() 
url = qr.create(Qstr)
url.png(b,scale=a)
but = tk.Button(window,text="fill",command=fill).pack()
but2 = tk.Button(window,text="press here",command=clicked).pack()
window.geometry('1920x1080')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code.  And `txt`, `txt2` and `txt3` are all `None` because you have chained `tk.Entry()` with `pack()`.

Comment: Thank you sir for responding, Sir so what changes should I make

Comment: You need to separate, for example, the line `txt = tk.Entry(...).pack()` into two lines: `txt = tk.Entry(...)` and `txt.pack()`.  Same applies to `txt2` and `txt3`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks a lot sir, I don't know how to thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @acw1668 states, you need to spereate the `txt = tk.Entry(...).pack()` into two lines.

This would be your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pyqrcode as qr
import png
from pyqrcode import QRCode
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("QR")
label = tk.Label(window,text="QR maker",font=("Helvetica",50))
label.pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="Enter link",font=("Helvetica",10))
label.pack()
txt = tk.Entry(window,width=50)
txt.pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="Enter size",font=("Helvetica",10))
label.pack()
txt2 = tk.Entry(window,width=10)
txt2.pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="enter name",font=("Helvetica",10)).pack()
txt3 = tk.Entry(window,width=50)
txt3.pack()

def clicked():
    Qstr = txt.get()
    a = int(txt2.get())
    b = txt3.get() 
    url = qr.create(Qstr)
    url.png(b,scale=a)
    but = tk.Button(window,text="fill",command=fill)
    but.pack()
but2 = tk.Button(window,text="press here",command=clicked)
but2.pack()
window.geometry('1920x1080')
window.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!